# get xyz from 6dof angles

Tags: ros, forward-kinematics, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have" robotic arm" and planned path values. The path includes 6 angles array for "robotic arm" joints. 
how can i get xyz (coordinate) from 6dof joint angles  
thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393808/get-xyz-from-6dof-angles/) by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-01-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-01-06**:
Are you going to code with `roscpp` or `rospy`? Do you want to do a linear algebra math calculation, or do you want to configure `moveit` and get the answer from one of its API methods?

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2022-01-06**:
im using roscpp.
i want to configure moveit and get the answer from one of its API methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This page will point you in the right direction. You want the "forward kinematics" section.

http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/robot_model_and_robot_state/robot_model_and_robot_state_tutorial.html#forward-kinematics

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2022-01-06**:
thank you so much